# How to change RabbitMQ node name without changing my hostname

Tags: rabbitmq

How do I change the RabbitMQ node name without changing my host name?

I am using Windows, and I added these variables:

```
set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5674
set COMPUTERNAME=192.168.10.1
set RABBITMQ_NODENAME="rabbitmq_%RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT%"
```

to `rabbitmq-server.bat`.

In the monitor page, the node name of this Rabbit instance is still `rabbitmq_5674@SH-abcde`, where this `SH-abcde` is my COMPUTERNAME. Is it possible to set RabbitMQ node name to `rabbit_5672@192.168.10.1`
without changing my computer name?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not modify the batch files that ship with RabbitMQ. The correct place to set variables is in the `%AppData%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq-env-conf.bat` file (where %AppData% is for the administrative user that installed RabbitMQ).

Second, it is not recommended to use an IP address in the node name. Try it if you like, but you may have issues.

So, here is what I recommend if you really wish to have `_5672` as part of the node name:

- Log in with the same administrative user that installed RabbitMQ
- Create the `%AppData%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq-env-conf.bat` file with this content:

  `set NODENAME=rabbitmq_5672@192.168.10.1`
- Open the "RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)" start menu item
- Stop RabbitMQ using `.\rabbitmq-service.bat stop`
- Remove the `%AppData%\RabbitMQ\mnesia\*` directories since they will be based on the previous node name. You will lose messages if any are there.
- Uninstall the Windows service: `.\rabbitmq-service.bat remove`
- Re-install the Windows service: `.\rabbitmq-service.bat install`
- Start the Windows service: `.\rabbitmq-service.bat start`

Comment: Many thanks! I tried to add set NODENAME to rabbitmq-env-conf.bat, but rabbit reported "Can't set short node name", and refused to start. Seems this works the same as I set the RABBITMQ_NODENAME, Is there anything else I should do?