# Is it possible to reconfigure Rabbit MQ once you have changed machine to point at the new machine without uninstalling or demising it

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I've come into an issue post install of Rabbit MQ where it was all set up and configured with the web apps on the machine and communicating to local applications however the machine had to be moved to a different tranch of machines and renamed as a result. Now Rabbit MQ can no longer serve or handle comms as intended as it's config points to rabbit@PREVIOUS_MACHINE instead of rabbit@CURRENT_MACHINE.

In the rabbit MQ config however, to complicate this, there was some configuration that was done from the users on the system that were fed into the local apps that are then encrypted into that local app's database and used for communicating with all the local apps. the issue here is if I drop and recreate Rabbit MQ a make a new user this won't align to what the other internal apps are using and I believe they are not configurable post install so a reinstall of everything is the potential impact.

the question is, is it possible to re-config or update the current RabbitMQ installation files to now point at the local machine name instead of the previous machine name AND I guess by proxy is this something that would even work. The docs over at rabbitmq don't quite deal with this specific scenario, unfortunately from what I've read through.

Answer (score 0):

so i want to confirm that RMQ is the absolute dogs tits of a black magic box.

anyway,

following these steps from here minus the first two

[How to change RabbitMQ node name without changing my hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112088/how-to-change-rabbitmq-node-name-without-changing-my-hostname)

this is the inverse of my problem pretty much. But for those in the future who have this issue;

I had Rabbit MQ on another machine installed and running, the machines name was changed and the solution was to uninstall the service, delete the db and reinstall the service. SOMEHOW rmq manages to keep the config knowledge of all the queues that were in the db in the system and when you reinstall the service it brings all the queues back as well. the only issue I had after that was to remember my username and password that were not default user set ups and I did so that solved my issue. still have no idea how RMQ manages to remember the previous configs despite deleting the local db, crazy cool. very grateful to whoever built that into the tool